# How long should the initial creation of my RAID 5 Array take? This seems ridiculous

Tags: linux, centos, raid, mdadm, raid5

I'm building a raid 5 array with 3 1.5TB drives on CentOS 5.5 using mdadm.  Everything seems to be working fine, except it's taking forever and I'm not sure if that's normal.  It's going on 6 hours now and /proc/mdstat says it's only at 6% (@ ~37MBps).  At this rate it's going to take the better half of a week to finish.

I've never setup a raid before so I'm not sure if I did something wrong. It seems like the initial setup should be a lot faster since there is no data on any of the drives.

Also, after I have the raid set up I've got data to transfer over from a drive then I'll be adding it to the array.  Is it going to take a similar amount of time to grow the array after?  I know they're huge hard drives but this seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 4):

There have been many other questions asking this (others will surely post comments with them), but I happen to have this sitting open:

[HowTo: Speed Up Linux Software Raid Building And Re-syncing](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-raid-increase-resync-rebuild-speed.html)

In summary: change your `/proc/sys/dev/raid/{speed_limit_max,speed_limit_min}` to something larger.

From the article:

> To see current limits, enter:
>
> `sysctl dev.raid.speed_limit_min`
>
> `sysctl dev.raid.speed_limit_max`
>
> To increase speed, enter:
>
> `echo value > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min`
>
> OR
>
> `sysctl -w dev.raid.speed_limit_min=value`
>
> Bitmaps optimize rebuild time after a crash, or after removing and re-adding a device. Turn it on by typing the following command:
>
> `mdadm --grow --bitmap=internal /dev/md0`
>
> Once array rebuild or fully synced, disable bitmaps:
>
> `mdadm --grow --bitmap=none /dev/md0`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really didn't see this when searching.  I went ahead and implemented the changes but didn't any increase in speed.  I asked this on reddit.com too and someone mentioned that the array is still usable while the initial creation is running, and lo and behold, it is,  so it's formatting now.